# to "break out" something in a context

Tags: word-meaning

Now I am reading [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/lifestyle/collector-is-beyond-obsessed-with-nikes-i-once-had-600-pairs-of-brand-new-air-jordans-in-my-size-175307268.html) and I don't understand this line with sorry.

> “Times have definitely changed a lot but my love of the Air Jordan has not,” Geller says, noting that he and his wife were married on 11/11, for which they each **broke out** a fresh pair of Nike Jordan 11s.

I think the verb ( bold one ) break out means "to buy", but my googling by "break out buy meaning" doesn't produce anything such. Could someone help me, will you?

I appreciate your support in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the entry for “broke out”](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/broke+out) in the Free Dictionary

> 7. verb To present something for use, especially something that had been stored out of sight or concealed.
>      *Break out the champagne—we've got an engagement to celebrate!*

In many of the meanings listed for “to break out”, there’s a sense of unexpectedness and suddenness.

Comment: After I asked at another forum [https://www.englishforums.com/English/ToBreakContext/bxvhmn/post.htm], the answer there was completely different. If your answer were correct, then it would sound a bit strange to me since they bought the Jordan 11 for their marriage. Anyway thank you for your support.

Comment: @KentaroTomono The post you refer to has been deleted. For what it's worth, I completely agree with this answer. I can't imagine how the expression could mean something different in this context. (Their love of Air Jordans was such that they marked the occasion of their wedding with new pairs.)

Comment: @Jason Bassford The post you ( or I ) mentioned is still alive. link[https://www.englishforums.com/English/ToBreakContext/bxvhmn/post.htm]. 
  The answerer said, "It's AmE. It means to start using something in order to make it comfortable." he and his girlfriend ( or his bride ) were married on 11/11. which had been scheduled about the detail of the day far prior to the bridal day, so that the answerer's answer "to start using something in order to make it comfortable" sounds very fine to me. On the contrary, sorry Colleen, I can not read the nuance of "unexpectedness" or "suddenness"

Comment: from the article.

Comment: @JasonBassford I am sorry I don't know why the redirection doesn't work. But at the forum I checked it's still there.

Comment: @KentaroTomono The expression used to start using something in order to make it comfortable is [*break* ***in***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/break%20in). As in " : to overcome the stiffness or newness of // *break in* a pair of shoes." *Break out* and *break in* have very different meanings.

Comment: @JasonBassford Jee. So Colleen's definition is correct? Phrasal verbs especially consisted of easy words are very tormenting lol. Anyway, thank you for your info^^.

Comment: @KentaroTomono Yes, at least according to my own usage and dictionaries. :)

Comment: @KentaroTomono The reason the link doesn't work is because of the bracket. If you don't put a space after, the code that changes text into live links thinks it is part of the URL. If you just paste the URL, it should work: https://www.englishforums.com/English/ToBreakContext/bxvhmn/post.htm

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks for the tip and your answer^^. Appreciate it(m_m).